# How azure served app service handle scale up in price?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I am thinking of purchasing a 3 year reserved app service plan on azure.

For my site, normally 1 or 2 instances are just good enough, but in the busy time, I have rules to autoscale the site out to 10 instances.

If I buy a 3 year reserved app service plan and my site auto scale out, will I be charged by the reserved price or pay as you go price?

from their [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/reservations/prepay-app-service), my feeling is that I will be charged by pay as you go price.Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the reservation agreement is just a **discount that will apply to the number of running instances that match the reservation scope and attributes**. So any extra instances will be charged using your standard rate.

This rate will depend on the type of subscription you use for paying for the reservation. If you have an individual pay-as-you-go subscription, extra app services will be charged by pay-as-you-go price. However, if you have an enterprise agreement, the price will be different and will depend on the agreement.